# KineticJS 5.0 - image drag and resize

Tags: javascript, html, image, kineticjs

I'm trying to resize images using KineticJS library with drag and drop technique. The code works perfect with v4.5.3 of the library - when I drag an anchor, the image is resizing. But after I updated KineticJS to 5.0, anchors are moving correctly, but the image isn't - nothing happens.

Here are fiddles with both versions (only diff is KineticJS version):
- kineticJS 4.5.3: http://jsfiddle.net/uAK9k/1/
- kineticJS 5.0: http://jsfiddle.net/uAK9k/

I think the problem is in `update(activeAnchor)` function, but I can't resolve this...
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some api changes:

1. `setPosition(x,y)` -> `setPosition({x:x, y: y})`
2. `setSize(width, height)` -> `setWidth(width);setHeight(height)`

http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/hseUk/

Comment: or `setSize({width: newWidth, height: newHeight});`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for image resize as well for the image distortion issue when you resize with anchor on the negative side

[Kinetic JS - problems trying to resize images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530496/kinetic-js-problems-trying-to-resize-images)

Here it is Fiddle:

```
image.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition());

image.setSize({
        width : width,
        height : height
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/aBkYb/